# What is easier to use or more implemented these days a:hover or javascript coding for changes on links?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, onmouseover

So I've been debating there are two different ways I can change my links one is through CSS:

```
     a {
     color: black;
     background-color: goldenrod;
     }
     a:hover {
     color: goldenrod;
     background-color: black;
     }
```

Then there is the javascript way:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', menuChange);

    function menuChange(){
        document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].style.color = "goldenrod";
        document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].style.background = "black";
     }

     document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].addEventListener('mouseout', menuNormal);

    function menuNormal(){
        document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].style.color = "black";
        document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].style.background = "goldenrod"; }
```

Both are reasonably useful in there comparisons except for the CSS once visited the color changes even if I add a:visited { etc... }. I'm wondering if one is going to be outdated soon or not like the CSS version has been used since 2000 maybe a year or two earlier when it came out. but the javascript version seems like it will never go wrong. so my question is which should i use for my website the javascript link change or the CSS? Please let me know the advantages and disadvantages of both. as I'm creating a site for a company and am contemplating on which to use?

Comment: I personally don't use JS for hover states of any kind. There was a time when `:hover` only worked with certain elements and if you want a fancy button (before border radius, gradients etc.) you had to use JS to adjust your image sprites. Unless it's something that can't be done with pure CSS, I don't do it. At least not for the basics.

Comment: so now with html5 and CSS3 a:hover works with all elements or atleast most. without the colour change after you click on the link when coming back to it? after answering those two questions your basic answer to this to me seems that u would choose the CSS hover over javascript as stated above. what about browser compatibility also inherited to the question?

Comment: `CSS once visited the color changes`. Not unless you choose it to be so. Hover color changes are very basic CSS, and definitely the job of CSS rather than JS. Browser compatibility is not an issue in this regard.

Comment: I think doing thing with css is better than involving a scripting a language that could do the same thing. I also think that  pseudo-class selectors is a pretty standard way to do link events and are not going away any time soon. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to use CSS whenever you can for styling concerns. Javascript should only every be used to style elements when you have to calculate some width or height that for one reason or another you can't achieve in CSS.

Just looking at the two solutions you can see how much less code you have to write with CSS to achieve the same effect, and if your javascript doesn't load before the user hovers over the element, the effect won't work in javascript anyway.

Additionally, using CSS you'll only have to go back and forth between two documents instead of three when you want to change the styling on your page.

A couple points of advice for CSS hovers: Always add a:focus to your a:hover declarations, i.e.

```
a:hover, a:focus{
   color: goldenrod;
   background-color: black;
}
```

So when the link is clicked on the style won't change before the page redirects.

Also, since the anchor tag is inline, and you're using a background color to highlight the hover, I'd suggest giving the link a display of block and some padding to make sure the background shows up nicely.

```css
a {
    color: black;
    background-color: goldenrod;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: goldenrod;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: Don't do it in JavaScript.

Link hovering is related to presentation, and you don't want to deal with that within a script. With not-too-recent-anymore features brought in CSS3, there shouldn't be a lot of use cases where scripts are needed to decide how things look and behave when the mouse gets over.

JavaScript is meant to make pages interactive, for example a click on a button, which does an operation according to what the user wants it to do. These interactions are assuming that the user is using a browser that supports a decent version of JavaScript. This is perfectly legit in my opinion to inform the user that he must enable JavaScript or even that he needs to get a newer browser to be able to do so. Where it comes messy is when the user needs to run some scripts in order to show the page correctly. He doesn't expect that and might get confused if something breaks into the UI and it's not caused by the presentation rules.

You should always draw a clear line between presentation and interaction. This is way easier to implement and also easier to manage. It may also come handy for performance, as scripts won't use hardware acceleration to speed things up, while CSS does it nicely when required or on-demand.